# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription}

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter osm plugin here. I am able to get the marker icon in android but unable to get it in ios. I am getting the above mentioned error whenever i am trying to get it in ios. what can i do to resolve it. the below is the method i am calling to get the marker icons.

```
  Future<void> mapIsInitialized() async {
   
    for (var item in responseData) {
      if (item is Map<String, dynamic>) {
        double? latitude = item['latitude'];
        double? longitude = item['longitude'];
        DateTime createdOn = DateTime.parse(item['createdOn']);
        String formattedDate = DateFormat('MMM d, y').format(createdOn);
 
        if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
          DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
          int daysDifference = currentDate.difference(createdOn).inDays;
          if (daysDifference <= 7) {
            geoPoints.add(GeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude));
            GeoPoint myCustomPoint =
                GeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude);
            await controller!.addMarker(myCustomPoint);
            await controller!.setMarkerIcon(
                myCustomPoint,
                const MarkerIcon(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person_pin,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    size: 48,
                  ),
                ));
          } else if (daysDifference <= 14) {
            geoPoints.add(GeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude));
            GeoPoint myCustomPoint =
                GeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude);
            controller!.addMarker(
              myCustomPoint,
            );
            await controller!.setMarkerIcon(
                myCustomPoint,
                const MarkerIcon(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person_pin,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    size: 48,
                  ),
                ));
          } else {
            geoPoints.add(GeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude));
            GeoPoint myCustomPoint =
                GeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude);
            await controller!.addMarker(myCustomPoint);
            await controller!.setMarkerIcon(
                myCustomPoint,
                const MarkerIcon(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person_pin,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    size: 48,
                  ),
                ));
          }
        }
      }
    }
 
    await controller!.setZoom(zoomLevel: 15);
 
    final bounds = await controller!.bounds;
  }
```